# How to find $S$ such that $S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to find $S$ such that $$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)3^n}$$

I know I have somehow to manipulate a integrals and derivative but I can't see how.

I'd love if anyone can solve me this question with full solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the fact that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n=\frac{1}{1-a}$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{-x}{3}\right)^n=\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{3}}=\frac{3}{3+x}$$

$$g(x)=f(x^2)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{3^n}$$

Then use the fact that derivative of $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ is $x^{2n}$

$$h(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)3^n}$$

Now if we take $x=1$ :

$$S=h(1)=\int_0^1\frac{3}{3+t^2}dt$$

Note that derivative of $\arctan(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did there?

Comment: I added two sentences to explain.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it..

Comment: Ok, after reading it 5 times .. I've understand nothing. 

Who is $t$? I'm not using a $x$ variable at all in my original series .. what did you did there?

Comment: The question "who is $t$" means that you don't know what is an integral. For $x$, I just take $x=1$ at the end. But if you want to use derivatives and integrals, you need some variable.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^n}{2n+1} = \dfrac{\tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{z})}{\sqrt{z}}$$

Comment: I've never seen $tanh^{-1}$ function so I guess there's might other way?